# exc_bad_instruction exc_i386_invop when i sending va_list to my other function

Tags: ios, objective-c, variadic-functions

I am developing for iphone.
I have log function, and this one works great

```
void _log_p(NSString* format, ...)
{
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, format);
    NSString* text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:argList];
    va_end(argList);
}
```

But when i try to send argList to another function i get exc_bad_instruction exc_i386_invop

```
void _log(LogLevel level, NSString* format,...)
{
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, format);
    NSString* text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:argList];
    va_end(argList);
}
void _log_p(NSString* format, ...)
{
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, format);
    _log(LogLevelPublic, format, argList);
    va_end(argList);
}
```

on the line NSString* text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:argList];

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm no expert on Objective C, but: You cannot forward a `va_list` to another function which takes variadic arguments via `...`. You would need a different version of the function which accepts a `va_list`. For example `printf` versus `vprintf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is not possible to forward variadic arguments. See: http://c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html